# Show the button at the table bottom even when the window is very small

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, tablesorter

I have a table sorter html page, the sample is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/12nt19vg/1/show/).

```
$('table').tablesorter({
    theme: 'blue',
    widgets: ['zebra', 'scroller'],
    widgetOptions: {
        scroller_height: 400
    }
});
```

How can I make the bottom button visible even when the windows height is very small (say, can only show one or two rows)? Ideally scroller_height can be some type like $(window).height()/2 and it can automatically update when the window is resized.
The expected is that even when the window is small, the bottom button appears in the screen without scroll action.

Comment: I think this should be tagged css as well.

Comment: thanks, css is added

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to make the scroller window dynamically adjust its height, there are two demos on the [main wiki page](https://github.com/Mottie/tablesorter/wiki#widgets) under Widgets > Scroller.

- http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/txLp4xuk/2/
- http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/abkNM/8037/

Essentially, all you need to do is adjust the outer scroll window height

```
$('.tablesorter-scroller-table').css({
  height: '',
  'max-height': height + 'px'
});
```

[Here is the demo you shared](http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/12nt19vg/28/) updated, and has a minimum height set to 100px.

Comment: Thank you. It's perfect.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say that there are a few ways to achieve what you want, and one easy way is to:

1. create a function that checks the visibility of your table versus the viewport;

Code below:

```
function checkVisible() {
   var bottom_of_table = $("#mytable").offset().top + $("#mytable").outerHeight();
   var bottom_of_screen = $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height();
        if(bottom_of_screen > bottom_of_table){
            $("#buttons-container").removeClass('bottom-fixed');        
        }
        else {
            $("#buttons-container").addClass('bottom-fixed');
        }
    }
```

2. If it exceeds the viewport, add a CSS class to your buttons container that fixes it to the bottom of the screen.  Otherwise, remove this class and display the button container normally, at the bottom of the table.

You'd want to run this function-check on load and on window resize, as follows:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    checkVisible();
    $(window).on('resize', checkVisible);
});
```

I've updated your fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/12nt19vg/12/show/

Try resizing the window and let me know if this is the behavior you're looking for.

**EDIT:** Incorporating your additional spec in the comments, I've added an outer div to your buttons container and modified your CSS to visually create the effect that I think you're looking for.

Please take a look at this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/12nt19vg/27/show/

Comment: It looks good. Is it possible to leave some space between the table and the button even when the window is small? Now the button is overlap on the table.